# Shape mismatch: if categories is an array, it has to be of shape (n_features,)

Tags: python, machine-learning, anaconda, data-science

Here is the code I'm trying to execute to encode the values of the first column of my data set using dummy values.

```
import numpy as py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
 

DataSet = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
x=DataSet.iloc[:, :-1].values
y=DataSet.iloc[:,3].values

from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer=SimpleImputer(missing_values=py.nan,strategy='mean')
imputer=imputer.fit(x[:, 1:3])
x[:, 1:3]=imputer.transform(x[:, 1:3])


from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
onehotencoder=OneHotEncoder(categories=[0])
x=onehotencoder.fit_transform(x).toarray()
```

Here's the data I'm working on

```
France  44.0    72000.0
Spain   27.0    48000.0
Germany 30.0    54000.0
Spain   38.0    61000.0
Germany 40.0    63777.7
France  35.0    58000.0
Spain   38.777  52000.0
France  48.0    79000.0
Germany 50.0    83000.0
France  37.0    67000.0
```

I'm getting a error stating

```
Shape mismatch: if categories is an array, it has to be of shape (n_features,).
```

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Is that all the code, or there something more?

Comment: Thats the area in the code which is giving me an error. However, I have put the entire code in my question for your reference now.

Comment: categories=[0] seems wrong, are you sure you want to one hot encode the second ?

Answer (score 1):

Your second doesn't seem to be a categorical features, you should only one_hot_encode features which can take a finite number of discrete value. Like the first column which can only take a limited number of value ('spain', 'germany', 'france')
If you only encode de the first column you can do:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
onehotencoder=OneHotEncoder(categories=[['France','Germany','Spain']])
x_1=onehotencoder.fit_transform(x[:,0].reshape(-1, 1)).toarray()
x = np.concatenate([x_1,x[:,1:]], axis=1)
```

and then your data will be in the form:

```
France Germany Spain score
1      0       0     44.0
0      0       1     27.0
...
```

Also, You only have 3 columns on your data but you're calling the fourth column with y=DataSet.iloc[:,3].values (first column start at index 0 -> .iloc[:,3] should give 4th column, then.

Answer (score 0):

```
#  Encoding categorical data [country]
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder , OneHotEncoder
#label_encoder object
label_encoder_X = LabelEncoder()
#Encode labels in columns
X[ : , 0] = label_encoder_X.fit_transform(X[: , 0])

# creates a binary column for each category
onehot_encoder=OneHotEncoder(categories=[[ 0 , 1 , 2 ]])
onehot_encoder=onehot_encoder.fit_transform(X[:,0].reshape(-1, 1)).toarray()
X = np.concatenate([onehot_encoder,X[:,1:]], axis=1)
```

Comment: A good answer always explain beside code that what was wrong and what changes caused the problem to resolve