# Shape mismatch with manual categories in OrdinalEncoder

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to encode an ordinal column by using the OrdinalEncoder from sklearn. Sample data could be the following:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
import numpy as np
X = np.array([-1, -2, -3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 1, 4, -1]).reshape(-1,1)

enc = OrdinalEncoder()
enc.fit(X)
enc.transform(X)

enc2 = OrdinalEncoder(categories = np.arange(-3, 5))
enc2.fit(X)
ValueError: Shape mismatch: if categories is an array, it has to be of shape (n_features,).
```

I want to be able to input the categories manually so the already existing question ([Shape mismatch: if categories is an array, it has to be of shape (n_features,)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62633492/shape-mismatch-if-categories-is-an-array-it-has-to-be-of-shape-n-features)) is not of much help.
My problem is that I don't understand the error. The shape of the categories is (to my mind) correct:

```
np.arange(-3, 5).shape
Out [1]:(8,)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [help page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html):

```
Parameters
categories‘auto’ or a list of array-like, default=’auto’
Categories (unique values) per feature:

‘auto’ : Determine categories automatically from the training data.

list : categories[i] holds the categories expected in the ith column. The passed categories should not mix strings and numeric values, and should be sorted in case of numeric values.
```

So you need provide a list or array, and within it, each subelement would hold the categories. In your example, since there is only 1 column in the data to be fitted, it would be:

```
enc2 = OrdinalEncoder(categories = [np.arange(-3, 5)])
enc2.fit(X)
OrdinalEncoder(categories=[array([-3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4])])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I got it now. So if I have two columns for the encoder I will use [array(), array()].